# Extract file names from Posh-SSH Get-SFTPChildItem output in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sftp, posh-ssh

I want to take this part

> REGISTRATION_ELI_20221222_071008.csv

from this PowerShell output of Posh-SSH `Get-SFTPChildItem`

> Name REGISTRATION_ELI_20221222_071008.csv, Length 0, User ID 1142,
> Group ID 1220, Accessed 12/21/2022 3:00:47 PM, Modified 12/21/2022
> 3:00:47 PM

How can I get it?

```
#Date
$time = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd") 

#Setting credentials for the user account
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("gomgom", $password)

$SFTPSession = New-SFTPSession -ComputerName 172.16.xxx.xxx -Credential $Credential -AcceptKey

# Set local file path and SFTP path
$LocalPath = "D:\WORK\Task - Script\20221010 - AJK - ITPRODIS380 - upload file csv ke sql server\csvfile"

$FilePath = Get-SFTPChildItem -SessionId $SFTPSession.SessionId "/Home Credit/Upload/" | Select-String -Pattern "REGISTRATION_ELI_$([datetime]::Now.toString('yyyyMMdd'))" 
$FilePath
Remove-SFTPSession $SFTPSession -Verbose
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not parse the name from the string dump of the file object.

The Posh-SSH `Get-SFTPChildItem` returns SSH.NET `SftpFile`, which has `Name` attribute:

```
$FilePath.Name
```

*(though then the `$FilePath` is actually a confusing variable name, as it's an object, not a mere path string)*

Answer (score -1):

You can dig into the Regex library and extract it out using Regex

```
$test = "Name REGISTRATION_ELI_20221222_071008.csv, Length 0, User ID 1142, Group ID 1220, Accessed 12/21/2022 3:00:47 PM, Modified 12/21/2022 3:00:47 PM"
$matches = [regex]::Match($test,"REGISTRATION.+\.csv")
$Matches.Value
```

Comment: it didn't work, no results came up

Comment: @Titanixx When I run those 3 lines of code, I get the desired output. Are you sure the get-sftpchilditem command is actually returning the output?

Comment: Yes, I am very sure and have tried it

Comment: @Titanixx Can you run the following commend and let me know the output? 

`$FilePath = get-sftpchilditem -SessionId $SFTPSession.SessionId "/Home Credit/Upload/";
write-output "Debug";
write-output $FilePath;`

If there is nothing after "Debug", then your command is writing it directly to the console and everything becomes trickier. Otherwise, the object type might not be a string and require some extra processing

Comment: This is the output 
FullName       : /Home Credit/Upload/REGISTRATION_ELI_20191006_071047.csv
LastAccessTime : 12/21/2022 11:00:28 AM
LastWriteTime  : 10/30/2019 11:30:38 AM
Length         : 2464584
UserId         : 1021

FullName       : /Home Credit/Upload/REGISTRATION_ELI_20210419_071056.csv
LastAccessTime : 12/21/2022 11:00:29 AM
LastWriteTime  : 4/19/2021 12:37:14 PM
Length         : 1828502
UserId         : 1021

Comment: and there is some output with different file names again @Shadowzee

Comment: and i just need **/Home Credit/Upload/REGISTRATION_ELI_20191006_071047.csv**

Answer (score -1):

$FilePath | Select-String -Pattern 'Name\s(.*?),' -AllMatches| Foreach-Object {$*.Matches} | Foreach-Object {$*.Groups[1].Value}